# Is it possible to run a NodeJS app using phonegap?

Tags: node.js, cordova

I have a web app that is hosted on a web server that was created using NodeJS (http://www.ruffle.us). What I want to do is make this web app into a mobile application gaining access to the contact list to enter phone numbers. I have looked at technologies such as phonegap/cordova for this task but am still unsure from the documentation. Any experience or input on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Cordova provides a browser environment, so you can't run Node.js in it. But you can of course run your web frontend inside Cordova and use it to get access to device APIs like the contact list and communicate with your server.